# Are Apache's LinearInterpolator and SplineInterpolator thread-safe?

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-math

I have utilized `org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.LinearInterpolator` and `org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.SplineInterpolator` in the following way:  I initialized `SPLINE_INTERPOLATOR` as static final

```
private static final SplineInterpolator SPLINE_INTERPOLATOR = new SplineInterpolator();
```

and let multiple processes use it to interpolate some data `x` and `y` (`SPLINE_INTERPOLATOR.interpolate(x, y)`).  Yesterday, a colleague asked me whether this usage of `SplineInterpolator` is legit, i.e. whether it is thread-safe.  I googled for answers, but couldn't find anything.  Does anyone know whether `SplineInterpolator` is thread-safe?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: General rule is to assume it is *not* thread-safe unless the documentation explicitly states that it is. Alternatively, you can check the source code itself for unsafe constructs.

Comment: SplineInterpolator appears to be threadsafe.

Comment: This is great to hear, thank you MeBigFatGuy.  And I do agree with you, James K Polk, that I should opt to be safe and assume it to not be in case I am unsure...